# Is there any memory-saving way to calculate Pearson correlation coefficient of two sparse matrix?

Tags: python, scipy

vec1 and vec2 are both 1x200000 sparse matrix.
I want to calculate the Pearson correlation coefficient between them (equivalent to scipy.stats.pearsonr). Is there any way?

Comment: "memory-saving" over what alternative?

Comment: Comparing with transforming both of them to dense matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

200k elements is usually not considered a lot, you probably can just convert them to dense matrices and use [scipy.stats.pearsonr](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html).

For reference though, see my implementation for sparse vectors below.

Note that the numeric error is quite big, so the last assertion mostly fails.
Also note the trick is to put the scalar subtraction outside the sum in order to keep all operations sparse.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse
from scipy.stats import pearsonr

def create_sparse_vector(n):
    return sparse.random(n,1)

def dense_pearsonr(x, y): 
    r, p = pearsonr(x.A.squeeze(), y.A.squeeze())
    return r

def sparse_pearsonr(x, y): 
    n = x.shape[0]
    assert(n == y.shape[0])
    mx = x.mean()
    my = y.mean()
    sx = np.sqrt(np.sum(x.multiply(x) - 2*mx*x) + mx**2)
    sy = np.sqrt(np.sum(y.multiply(y) - 2*my*y) + my**2)
    a = np.sum(x.multiply(y)) - n*mx*my
    b = sx*sy
    c = a / b 
    return min(max(c,-1.0),1.0)

N = 200000 
x = sparse.random(N,1)
y = sparse.random(N,1)
r1 = dense_pearsonr(x,y)
r2 = sparse_pearsonr(x,y)
print(r1)
print(r2)
assert(np.isclose(r1,r2)) # Warning: Assertion fails because of too big numerical error
```

Answer (score 1):

Define 2 sparse matrices:

```
In [15]: M1 = sparse.random(1,1000)
In [16]: M2 = sparse.random(1,1000)

In [17]: stats.pearsonr(M1.A[0], M2.A[0])
Out[17]: (0.20251345569257148, 1.0257264375653503e-10)
```

Same value:

```
In [23]: x=M1.A[0]; y=M2.A[0]
In [24]: x1=x-x.mean(); y1=y-y.mean()
In [25]: (x1*y1).sum()/np.sqrt((x1*x1).sum()*(y1*y1).sum())
Out[25]: 0.20251345569257148
```

But I can't do that with sparse matrices:

```
In [27]: M1.mean()
Out[27]: 0.0050088190479221925
In [28]: M1 - M1.mean()
...
NotImplementedError: subtracting a nonzero scalar from a sparse matrix is not supported
```

Subtracting a nonzero value from a sparse matrix means that it is no longer sparse.

---

Ignoring the means:

```
In [36]: (M1.multiply(M2)).sum()/np.sqrt((M1.multiply(M1)).sum()*(M2.multiply(M2)).sum())
Out[36]: 0.20828802559020454
```

Comment: the matrix I used is very sparse, so I tried to ignore M1.mean, I have got the result.